# Modifying multiple CSV files and saving them all as TXT in R

Tags: r, dataframe, csv

I have a folder containing several .csv files. I need to delete the first three rows and the very last row of all those .csv files and then save them all as .txt. All the files have the same format so it's always the same rows that I would need to delete.
I know how to modify a single dataframe but I do not know how to load, modify and save as txt several dataframes.
I am a beginner using R so I do not have examples of things I have tried yet.
Any help will be really appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A few questions: (1) You know how to modify dataframes. Do you know how to create them by reading in a CSV? (2) Do you know how to use `write.csv()` or `write.table()`? You can just make sure the filename ends in `.txt`. (3) Do you know how to use a `for` loop?

Comment: By "save them all as .txt", do you mean you want them as tab-separated files? Or something else? `.txt` doesn't have a strict definition.

Comment: I have used write.csv before and I have deleted rows before, but never on multiple dataframes. All I have right now is this: all_data=list.files(pattern='.*.csv')

Comment: @GregorThomas Yes, I want them tab delimited

Comment: @duckmayr I have codes that use for loops but I don't know very well how to use them, sorry.

Comment: I can read the files but that's as far as I go. all_data=list.files(pattern='.*.csv')
> all_data
 [1] "001SMPL.csv" "002SMPL.csv" "003SMPL.csv" "004SMPL.csv" "005SMPL.csv" "006SMPL.csv" "007SMPL.csv"
 [8] "008SMPL.csv" "009SMPL.csv" "010SMPL.csv" "011SMPL.csv" "012SMPL.csv" "013SMPL.csv" "014SMPL.csv"
[15] "015SMPL.csv" "016SMPL.csv" "017SMPL.csv" "018SMPL.csv" "019SMPL.csv" "020SMPL.csv" "021SMPL.csv"
[22] "022SMPL.csv" "023SMPL.csv" "024SMPL.csv" "025SMPL.csv"
>

Comment: You can read in the CSV files and ignore the first 3 rows with `skip=3` and specify how many rows to read using `nrows`.

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to start with stack overflow but the other comments about reproducible examples are worth thinking about for the future. My suggestion would be to write a function that reads, modifies, and writes and then loop it across all the files.

I can't tell exactly how to do this as I can't see your data but something like this should work:

```
library('tidyverse')

old_paths = list.files(
  path = your_folder,
  pattern = '\\.csv$',
  full.names = TRUE
)

read_write = function(path){

  new_filename = str_replace(
    string = path,
    pattern = '\\.csv$',
    replacement = '.txt'
  )

  read_csv(path) %>% 
    slice(-(1:3)) %>% 
    slice(-n()) %>% 
    write_tsv(new_filename) %>% 
    invisible()
}

lapply(old_paths, read_write)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It's my first question, so I am sure I will get better as asking in the future. I tried to find examples before asking but putting all of their suggestions together still didn't work because it was too advanced for me. Thank you for your help, I will try this.

Comment: Yes, this kind of question is a bit tougher to ask because it involves import/export and not data that others could easily put into the memory of our own computers. Good luck!

Comment: This sort of worked, except that it kept the first row, and deleted rows 2-4, I am assuming it thinks row 1 is the names, and kept it. Also it deleted all my columns but the first one. But it converted to TXT all the files which is a great improvement! :)

Comment: Ah, I see what you meant. I usually think of the row labeled as 1 in Excel as the 0th row which has the names. I think you can figure out how to modify the `slice` statements to get what you really wanted.

Comment: I get this error for all the files: Parsed with column specification:
cols(
 `path` = col_character()
)
Warning: 985 parsing failures.
row col  expected     actual                            file
  1  -- 1 columns 2 columns  'CPS Non Toxic TXT/001SMPL.csv'
  3  -- 1 columns 48 columns 'CPS Non Toxic TXT/001SMPL.csv'
  4  -- 1 columns 48 columns 'CPS Non Toxic TXT/001SMPL.csv'
  5  -- 1 columns 48 columns 'CPS Non Toxic TXT/001SMPL.csv'
  6  -- 1 columns 48 columns 'CPS Non Toxic TXT/001SMPL.csv'

Comment: The `readr` library only looks at the top of the dataset and makes assumptions about what types the data are based on that. If the data is very different later in the file it will not import correctly. You can read more about it [here](https://readr.tidyverse.org/articles/readr.html#column-specification) but it might be easy to just add `col_types = cols(.default = 'c')` to the `read_csv` call.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209717/discussion-between-clau-martinez-and-svenhalvorson).

Answer (score 1):

Let's do this for one data frame, *only referencing its file name*

```
input_file = "my_data_1.csv"
data = read.csv(input_file)
# modify
data = data[-(1:3), ] # delete first 3 rows
data = data[-nrow(data), ] # delete last row
# save as .txt
output_file = sub("csv$", "txt", input_file)
write.table(x = data, file = output_file, sep = "\t", row.names = FALSE)
```

Now we can turn it into a function taking the file name as an argument:

```
my_txt_convert = function(input_file) {
  data = read.csv(input_file)
  # modify
  data = data[-(1:3), ] # delete first 3 rows
  data = data[-nrow(data), ] # delete last row
  # save as .txt
  output_file = sub("csv$", "txt", input_file)
  write.table(x = data, file = output_file, sep = "\t", row.names = FALSE)
}
```

Then we call the function on all your files:

```
to_convert = list.files(pattern='.*.csv')
for (file in to_convert) {
  my_txt_convert(file)
}
# or
lapply(to_convert, my_txt_convert)
```

Comment: This did not work for me but it's definitely because of the way my .csv files are structures because I tested it with a different file and it works. With my original file it gives me an error: Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  more columns than column names

Comment: I would suggest asking a separate question to find the write command to read in the file.Open the file in a text editor (like RStudio) and show us the first few lines of the file in a new question.